# How to add video call to my website using Google Hangouts API?

Tags: google-api, google-hangouts

I want to add video call to my website using hangouts api. I referred the [Google Hangouts button documentation](https://developers.google.com/+/hangouts/button) and my code is :

```
<script src="https://apis.google.com/js/platform.js" async defer></script>
<div id="placeholder-div"></div>
<script>
  gapi.hangout.render('placeholder-div', { 'render': 'createhangout' });
</script>
```

It's not loading anything.

Comment: Try using the simpler markup from [render button using HTML5 markup](https://developers.google.com/+/hangouts/button#render_button_using_html5_markup).

Comment: I tried that it's not working is it working in your system?

Comment: It works just fine on [JS Bin](https://jsbin.com/viyufopuva/edit?html,js,output)

Comment: yeah its working on JSBin, i copied the same html content to my sample.html page its not working. Not sure very strange for me.

Comment: Thanks abraham, i tried the same thing in server side jsp its working :)

Comment: This looks like it can be closed as an unreproduceable issue.